# gcc --- __attribute__((interrupt( irq )))

Tags: gcc, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

i started with device driver for arm ... there i saw for each handler mention --- `__attribute__((interrupt( irq )))` -.I am confused how this attribute will place a call to our driver routine ..??

IRQ of arm have following Vector address--- 0x00000018 (or 0xFFFF0018) 
As there can be many interrupt handler on same line. Suppose if we have 4 device driver each with its own IRQ to be reistered.

Means some startup code will be provided by the GCC compiler for the IRQ handler & compiler will place call to our routine in that startup code for interrupt handler ..... Am i right ...?

Comment: If you want to ask if gcc somehow generates code to automagically install you interrupt routine - no, this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

From [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-interrupt-handler-functions-2592) for **interrupt** attribute:

> The compiler generates function entry and exit sequences suitable for use in an interrupt handler when this attribute is present.

You can use `objdump` easily to see how this attribute changes your binary which should clarify the situation for you much better.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute should ONLY be used by interrupt handler of the OS and NOT by interrupt handler of a specific driver. The OS will read the IRQ vector/number and call the appropriate driver function to service the IRQ. You only need to register your driver/ISR with the OS.